# Is guarding <, >, and & enough to sanitize HTML in Swing components?

Tags: java, html, swing, sanitization

I have an arbitrary string. I want to put `MyString` in a HTML document like

```
<html><body>Text bla <b>MyString</b> bla bla</body></html>
```

I do not want to allow MyString to do any HTML formatting with tags, but I also don't want to escape EVERY character using `&charcode;` (which is my fallback plan).

Is it enough to replace `<`, `>` and `&` with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` (and newline with `<br>`)? If not, what else?

Some more context: This is for putting user-provided strings in a formatted way in a JLabel, which also contains other text (so just styling the label is not enough).

Comment: @user2864740 Cool. Mind showing me one?

Comment: Hmm, I removed the previous comment to avoid going down the 'include library X' route. I also focused the question title to be specially wrt. usages in Swing, although such disagrees slightly with the first sentence which appears to imply a more general context. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html might be useful, although it does not directly answer this question. (There is an OWASP library for Java, which does include such support.)

Comment: @user2864740 Even that library does it in some way. I'm more interested in what is required to achieve that than in just plain using something. That's why I'd like to know if my thinking is correct and if not, where I'm wrong. :)

Comment: See Rule #1 from [the OWASP cheat-sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) link, which lists 6 characters to escape: `&, <, >, ", ', /`. Whether or not such are required (in all contexts)..

Comment: @user2864740 Already reading that, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2864740 Put that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2864740 wrote in the comments:

> See Rule #1 from [the OWASP cheat-sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) link, which lists 6
> characters to escape: &, <, >, ", ', /. Whether or not such are
> required (in all contexts).

Escaping these characters seemed to have been enough in my case.